# MyBatis Resolving parameter with multiple statements

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm trying to dynamically set the lock timeout for a query with MyBatis and PostgreSQL.

My Mapper looks like :

```
 @Select("SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '#{lockTimeout}s';"
   + "SELECT ......where id= #{myId} FOR UPDATE")
 MyObject select(@Param("lockTimeout") String lockTimeout, @Param("myId") String id);
```

It seems that there is a mismatch with parameters and I'm getting a

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Index of column out of range : 2, number of column 1.
```

`@SelectProvider` won't match in my case because my parameter lock timeout isn't static.

Does anyone have an idea how can I dynamically set the parameter lock timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgjdbc seems to execute each statement independently.
I would not recommend putting multiple statements in a single mapper statement as the behavior depends on the driver.
You should declare two methods and call them in the same session/transaction instead.

```java
@Update("select set_config('lock_timeout', #{lockTimeout}, true)")
void setLockTimeout(String lockTimeout);

@Select("SELECT ......where id= #{myId} FOR UPDATE")
MyObject select(@Param("myId") String id);
```

A few notes:

- `set_config()` is used as `SET LOCAL` does not seem to work with a `PreparedStatement`.
- `@Update` is used to apply the change immediately. If you use `@Select`, you may need to call `SqlSession#commit()` explicitly.
- Unlike your example, the parameter must include `s` i.e. `setLockTimeout("1s")`.
  If you prefer passing just a number, `#{lockTimeout} || 's'` should work.